# t-sql LIKE and special characters

Tags: t-sql, unicode, sql-like

"[" is not classed a unicode character http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Unicode_characters (my guess) as to why this wouldn't work:

```
declare @v nvarchar(255)
set @v =  '[x]825' 
select 1 
where  @v like  '[x]825'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`[]` defines a range of characters for a pattern match.  It has special meaning in a LIKE statement.  [Here's the documentation for it.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa933232%28SQL.80%29.aspx)

If you're looking for those characters explicitly, you'll need to escape them, like this:

```
declare @v nvarchar(255)
set @v =  '[x]825' 
select 1 
where  @v LIKE '![x]825' 
       ESCAPE '!'
```

Comment: He just did! Is there an sql setting to stop customers entering this? Ta

Answer (score 1):

[x] has a specific meaning to SQL server. The brackets are used for very basic regular expressions. SO what you are searching for is where the first character contains the letter X and of course that isn't the first character in your variable.

It is best not use like unless you intend to havea awildcard and it is a bad practice to have a wildcard be the first character as it makes the query use a table scan instead of an index.